# Legacy Hibernate one-to-many mapping with JPA

Tags: hibernate, set, jpa-2.0

I have a legacy Hibernate managed domain which I'm now trying to upgrade to a Spring Data JPA environment.

The Maven build is a success when run against the legacy Hibernate DAO.

But when I run the Maven build against the JPA entity manager, I get an exception on the one domain class that makes use of a one-to-many mapping.

Here is the domain class:

```
public class LinkCategory implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private int version;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Set<Link> links = new HashSet<Link>();

    public LinkCategory() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Set<Link> getLinks() {
        return this.links;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setLinks(Set<Link> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public void addLink(Link link) {
        if (link.getLinkCategory() != this) {
            if (link.getLinkCategory() != null) {
                link.getLinkCategory().links.remove(link);
            }
            link.setLinkCategory(this);
            this.links.add(link);
        }
    }

    public void removeLink(Link link) {
        if (link.getLinkCategory().getId() == this.getId() && this.getId() != null) {
            link.setLinkCategory(null);
            this.links.remove(link);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the Hibernate mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.thalasoft.learnintouch.core.domain.LinkCategory" table="link_category" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="native"><param name="sequence">sq_id_link_category</param></generator>
        </id>
        <version name="version" type="int">
            <column name="version" not-null="true" />
        </version>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="description" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <set name="links" inverse="true" order-by="list_order" cascade="all">
            <key column="category_id" />
            <one-to-many class="com.thalasoft.learnintouch.core.domain.Link" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The error I get is:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: java.util.Set, at table: LinkCategory, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(links)]

My version of Hibernate is: 3.6.9.Final
My version of Hibernate JPA 2 is: 1.0.1.Final
My version of Spring Data JPA is: 1.3.0.RELEASE

Any clue ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: can u show other class mapping

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by specifying the following annotation:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="linkCategory")
private Collection<Link> links;
```